Does accessing the 'Length' and 'Position' properties of a Stream have a significant impact on performance?
// Case 1 
while(true)
{
   int packetLength = GetPacketLength();
   byte[] data = br.ReadBytes(packetLength);
   if(data.length < packetLength)
   {
      Console.Write("end");
      break;
   }
}
// Case2
while(true)
{
   int packetLength = GetPacketLength();
   if(stream.Length - stream.Position < packetLength)
   {
      Console.Write("end");
      break;
   }
   byte[] data = br.ReadBytes(packetLength);
}

I have discovered that when reading and processing files using BinaryReader in a loop thousands of times, using case 1 is much faster than using case 2.
I'm already using it like case 1, but I'm curious why it is slower. That's why I'm writing this post.

That would depend on the implementation (eg https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/e126f8ff2e635ef104b8f1212ec76420f114e99d/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/FileStream.cs#L451 ?)

As you can see in the Stream source code, Length and Position are abstract so their implementation only depends on the sub classes which may or may not have a slow implementation.
You can check the documentation or source code of the Stream inheriting class you are using to determine if accessing these could lead to performance issues.

No need to look at the source code to see that these properties are abstract, this is also stated in the documentation

@KlausGütter I mean the source code of the Stream inheriting class, not Stream itself

eg if accessing .Position causes a system call, there would be a larger performance impact. But that would depend on the specific implementation. There will be some impact just because it is a virtual property and not just a field. FileStream for example has two branches for potential exceptions before loading a field.

Thanks for helping you guys. I'll check the things you guys told me.
